# Firebase Realtime Data, how to change a .child to a textfield value that the user inputs

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using firebase realtime database, i am trying to create a JSON that when the user inputs data instead of using an AutoId it puts it in from their email address or 'user' name?

The reason i need this is for when i receive the data, i need to know what email address each job links to so i can only show the data relevant to that job.

[image: xcode]

As seen in the code ive attempted to add the txtfield to each of the childs however this does not work.

```
func addedJob (){


    let key = ref.childByAutoId().key!

    //let email = ["email": txtEmail.text! as String]

    let job = ["id": key,
               "shipper": txtShip.text! as String,
               "consignee": txtCon.text! as String,
               "email": txtEmail.text! as String,
               "collection date": txtCol.text! as String,
               "delivery date": txtDel.text! as String,
               "freight": txtFreight.text! as String,
               "reference": txtRef.text! as String,
               "pod": txtPod.text! as String,]


    ref.child(email).setValue(job)

// not working 

ref.child(txtEmail.text! ?? "")

//Still not working this crashes every time
```

Full crash log:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010be481bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b3e6735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   firebarker2019                      0x000000010916e2fd +[FValidation validateFrom:validPathString:] + 253
    3   firebarker2019                      0x00000001090f551f -[FIRDatabaseReference child:] + 239
    4   firebarker2019                      0x000000010904cee5 $S14firebarker201914ViewControllerC8addedJobyyF + 7061
    5   firebarker2019                      0x000000010904b10a $S14firebarker201914ViewControllerC6submityySo8UIButtonCF + 58
    6   firebarker2019                      0x000000010904b14c $S14firebarker201914ViewControllerC6submityySo8UIButtonCFTo + 60
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000110553ecb -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000010ff8f0bd -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000010ff8f3da -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000010ff8e31e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 583
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000011058f0a4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2729
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00000001105907a0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4080
    13  UIKitCore                           0x000000011056e394 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001106435a9 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3054
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001106461cb __handleEventQueueInternal + 5948
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bdad721 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bdacf93 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bda763f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bda6e11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113f801dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    21  UIKitCore                           0x000000011055281d UIApplicationMain + 140
    22  firebarker2019                      0x000000010904f227 main + 71
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d894575 start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: what is your crash log? and have you tried `ref.child(txtEmail.text!).updateChildValues(job)`

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Check my updated comment.

Comment: Yes, still crashing, ive updated my question with the full crash log

Comment: what is `txtEmail.text!`

Comment: it is a UITextField

Comment: No I mean what value you are entering into textfield?

Comment: Just a unique email address with regards to the job, so when it comes to receive the data i can just pull that child which then will have all the information regarding that one job. If that makes sense?

Comment: `ref.child(txtEmail.text! ?? "")`. You shouldn't use an exclamation mark here `!` because it forces unwrapping before applying the onNil value. It should look like this: `ref.child(txtEmail.text ?? "")`

Comment: `txtEmail.text!` is OK. `UITextField` property `text` default value is already an empty string `""`. Even if you assign nit to text before accessing it, it won't return nil.  Just drop the nil coalescing operator `ref.child(txtEmail.text!)`

Comment: You should probably reconsider using email addresses as keys to your nodes. If an email address changes (which they do) then you'll have to go through every node in your entire database, read it in, delete it, and write it back out with the new email. That's cumbersome. Keep the AutoId for your keys - you can easily query for the email address to return that node and there are many other options as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with this code:

- Your email constant is a dictionary. You can not set a dictionary as the name of the child of the database.
- The text properties of text fields are strings. It is useless to cast them as String.
- When you try to set the txtEmail.text as the child you force unwrap it, so the nil coalescing operator does nothing.

Looking at your crash log the problem you are facing is clear. The message you are getting is: "**(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''** " This means that your text field's text property must always contain a value and must not contain special characters.

Unfortunately, all email addresses contain a dot, which is a special character not allowed for child names. I suggest you use another value (for example name, username etc).

So how you should fix this:

- To make sure that the text field always has a value I would not let the user initiate the saving to the firebase database until they entered a value in the text field. So before your function starts the upload check if textField.text has a value. If it hasn't show an alert which let's the user know that they must enter a value there.
- How to check for special characters: As I stated above, you should not use the email address, because it always has a dot in it. For safety however, you can use the following function to strip a string from all special characters. Use the stripped string as the child name.

  ```
  extension String {

  var stripped: String {
      let okayChars = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890")
      return self.filter {okayChars.contains($0) }
     }
  }
  ```

Use it like this: `let strippedString = myString.stripped`

Ask if you have any questions with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As error indicating that

```
reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
```

so you can not create a key which contains `'.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'` this characters.

One solution I can think of is you can convert `email`  string to `base64Encoded` and once you get it back from server you can get your email back from `base64Encoded` string.

Consider below code:

```
extension String {
    init?(base64Encoded: Data) {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64Encoded) else { return nil }
        self.init(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    init?(base64Encoded: String) {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64Encoded) else { return nil }
        self.init(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    var data: Data {
        return Data(utf8)
    }
    var base64EncodedData: Data {
        return data.base64EncodedData()
    }
    var base64EncodedString: String {
        return data.base64EncodedString()
    }
}
```

---

```
let email = "test1@gmail.com"

let base64Encoded = email.base64EncodedString // dGVzdDFAZ21haWwuY29t
let normalEmailFromBase64 = String(base64Encoded: base64Encoded) //test1@gmail.com
```

---

And you can set data with

```
ref.child(base64Email).updateChildValues(job)
```